# SQLClient running Varchar conversions on Datetimes and having errors

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclient

I'm trying to run an `UPDATE` command which stores `DateTime` data types in a SQL Server table, however whenever it reaches the line

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

the program fails with this error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

I have managed to gather that this probably means something about the `DateTime` format I'm using, but no matter what shape I attempt to wrestle the time into, it still spits out the exact same error.

The format that the data is stored in is en-GB and reads in as follows:

```
StartDateTime = DateTime.Parse(items[0], new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

When I attempt to store the time in SQL, I am currently using the following formatting:

```
const string ParamStart = "@NewStartDate";
command.Parameters.Add(ParamStart, System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = newStartDate;
```

Data stored in the SQL Server table is stored in this format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff
```

My SQL reader has no trouble taking the data in from the SQL Server, but as soon as I start using parameters it complains.

The really frustrating part is that elsewhere in the same file I have a `SELECT` command that uses exactly the same formatting to include the data in the query:

```
command.Parameters.Add(ParamStart, System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = startDate;
```

And this works fine.

The data type in SQL Server for that column is `datetime` which can not be null.

The query as it appears in my C# code:

```
string query = $"UPDATE [{DB_NAME}].[dbo].[{TABLE_BATCH}] SET [{COLUMN_START}] = {ParamStart}, [{COLUMN_MACHINE}] = {ParamMachine}," +
                $" [{COLUMN_SERIAL}] = {ParamSerial}, {(newBatch.EndDateTime != null ? $"[{COLUMN_END}] = {ParamEnd}, " : "")}[{COLUMN_COMPLETE}] = {ParamComplete}, [{COLUMN_IN_USE}] = {ParamInUse} {oldBatch.ToWhere()}";
```

Anything starting with `COLUMN_` or `Param` is simply a constant that contains just a string. It is used so that I can avoid typos and so that I can edit the code if the column names change.

The `ToWhere()` method creates a `WHERE` from an existing item that was pulled from the database moments beforehand. The `WHERE` uses an interpolated string so the parameter conversion shouldn't be happening there but I will post the format of the return clause anyway:

```
$"WHERE [StartDateTime] = '{StartDateTime}' AND [MachineID] = '{MachineID}' AND [BatchNumber] = '{BatchNumber}'" +
                $" AND [SAPOrderNumber] {sapString} AND [PartNumber] = '{PartNumber}' AND [LastSerialNumber] = {LastSerialNumber}" +
                $" AND [EndDateTime] {endDateString} AND [Complete] {completeString} AND [BatchInUse] {inUseString}";
```

What do I need to change about the format to make SQL Server recognise the date?

Comment: Dates are binary values like int and double, they have no format. Don't store dates as strings. Use the correct type - `date`, `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset`. If you store dates as strings you have a serious bug and quite probably unsalvageable garbage data. There's simply no way to say if `07/04/2021` is April 7th or July 4th

Comment: In C# use `DateTime`, not strings.

Comment: I am storing it as a DateTime.

Comment: If you do, where does the `varchar` come from? What does the query do? Post code that actually reproduces the problem. Somehow, somewhere, you're handling dates as text

Comment: The parameter is not the problem, whatever query you're trying to execute is. When `DATETIME` and `VARCHAR` values are combined, SQL Server will always prefer to convert the `VARCHAR` to a `DATETIME` for comparison purposes, not the other way around. As a result, if *any* `VARCHAR` value does not implicitly convert to a `DATETIME` using the server's language settings, you get this error. The solution is to fix the query so it uses an explicit conversion (or fix the data once and for all so there's no mix-and-match of types going on).

Comment: It has just occurred to me the one place where a DateTime is just plonked into the string and not parameterised is in the where clause. I'll be fixing that and checking again.

Comment: Using interpolated strings with queries is a red flag, of course, you want parameterization. You can still use parameters with dynamically constructed SQL. What you definitely want to avoid is interpolating `DateTime` values into strings, as you pretty much are required to always use `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")` or [suchlike](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166771/what-date-time-literal-formats-are-language-and-dateformat-safe) to ensure you get a literal format that will convert regardless of locale. And that's not even including the logic for `NULL`, of course.

Comment: Since I'm seeing confusion in other comments here: you can use a custom `IFormatProvider` with interpolated strings to create parameters instead of substituting the value directly, and it seems that may be what's going on. However, if that is the case, you do **NOT** want the query value wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: I also see this: `Data stored in the SQL Server table is stored in this format: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff`. If the column data type really  is `DateTime` (and it should be), that format is simply **not true**. When you see a value that looks like `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff`, this is just a **convenience provided by your tooling**. The actual format is **binary** an _not human readable_.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Binary is certainly human readable, just not very quickly or by most people :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be in my WHERE clause, the datetime was not necessarily formatted correctly in the interpolated string, and it did not occur to me until after updating this question.

Comment: Dates have no formats. End of story. **Don't** use interpolated strings, use parameters. Using interpolated strings *is* the bug. This leaves you wide open to SQL injection attacks and conversion errors like the one you encountered. If you used parameters instead, there would be no problems

Comment: `$" AND [EndDateTime] {endDateString}` what is this supposed to do? As it is, it's simply invalid SQL. Are you trying to pass the operator along with the value?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Like I said in the question, the data in that interpolated string only ever comes from the server itself. There is zero user input in this case which I think makes the case pretty safe from SQL injection.
Also that was using a check to either be "IS NULL" or "= 'EndDate'", this has since been removed to use parameterisation methods.

Comment: And you still got a bug. Because the *client* formatted those strings differently from the server. Besides, the code is still wide open to SQL injection. The data came from the server, but what if that data was tainted to begin with? What if `sapString` contained `=''; Drop Table Users;--`?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how that kind of bad data could get into the database without executing in the first place. But I do see your point. Would it be safe to presume that integer and bit data is safe to interpolate?

Comment: @Swyfte it is **NOT** safe to presume that integer and bit data is safe, because of custom numeric format options that allow users to tell the system to use arbitrary text in place of a negative sign or group separator. There are other ways to circumvent numeric data, too.